# How to handle a Perl array the correct way?

Tags: perl

I'm quite new in writing Perl code, so I'm hoping for some help here.

I'm querying a database, which works as long as I'm just selecting one row and write the queried variables into some variables in another database.

As soon as I want to create an array and do with multiple variables, what I am able to do with a single one, my code doesn't work.

Do you spot the mistake?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $host = "host";
my $database = "DBI:mysql:database";
my $tablename = "table";
my $user = "user";
my $pw = "password";

my $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`attribute`) FROM `table` WHERE `attribute` =".GETVALUE("attribute");

my $connect = DBI->connect($database, $user, $pw) or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;

my $sth = $connect->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

my $row;

my $sql2 = "SELECT `attribute2`,`name`, `adress` FROM `table` WHERE `attribute` =".GETVALUE("attribute");

my $sth2 = $connect->prepare($sql2);
$sth2->execute();

my(@attribute2, @name, @adress);

    while (($row) = $sth->fetchrow()){
        for (my $i = 0; $i < $row; $i++)
            {
                 SETVALUE("Variable".$i , my $name->[$i].", ". my $adress->[$i]);
            }
                 SETVALUE("CountAttribute", $row);
            }
```

`

I already tried to exchange "fetchrow" with "fetchrow_array" and "fetchrow_arrayref", but this didnt work either.

Comment: Thats the code that doesnt work. It just returns the "," but not the "$name" or the "$adress"

Comment: What are `GETVALUE()` and `SETVALUE()` doing? They seem to be subroutines that are part of your code, but they aren't included in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Accepting the comment that `fetchrow()` is an undocumented alias for `fetchrow_array()`:

The `fetchrow_array()` method returns the contents of the row, not an index. Assuming what you want to do is call `SETVALUE()` with each name and address, and then one last time with the number of rows fetched, your `while()` loop should be something along the lines of:

```
my $i = 0;
while ( my ( $attr2, $name, $addr ) = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
    SETVALUE( "Value$i", "$name, $addr" );
    $i++;
}
SETVALUE( "CountAttribute", $i );
```

Comment: This is a great approach- and you assumed right what i want to do. But that code justs sets the content of the first row correctly- I need to set several rows more.

Comment: I can not duplicate your results because I do not have the database, but each iteration of `fetchrow_array()` **should** retrieve a different row of the database. It might help to confirm how many rows are being fetched and what their values are. If your script can be run interactively, I would do this by inserting something like `warn "Debug - name '$name', addr '$addr'"` before the call to `SETVALUE()` and see if the results are what you expect. If they are, there is something going on inside `SETVALUE()`. If not, the query is not returning what you expect.